# Why am I sometimes getting strange FileNotFoundExceptions when starting a web application with tomcat via Intellij

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, intellij-idea, tomcat8.5

I'm working on a **Java 8 Web Application** with **Spring** and **Spring Security**. It is a simple Web-Application which is being built via aven into a war-File. My IDE is **Intellij IDEA Ultimate**, the application is being deployed with Intellij to a **Tomcat 8.5**. The build process uses **two Maven profiles**.

If I try to start the application via an Intellij Tomcat Run Configuration, I sometimes (not every time, which also is weird) get **FileNotFoundExceptions** for jars inside `target\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\`. The dependencies are all defined insided the pom-file, just like for any standard Maven-Project, so nothing fancy here. No relative or absolute file paths anywhere! If I check for the "missing" jars then I find them, they are all where they are supposed to be ("<%Project_Root%>\target\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\") but where Intellij says they aren't.

Example ErrorStack:

```java
    17-May-2019 13:23:11.715 SCHWERWIEGEND [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Exception starting Context with name [/collphir]
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/collphir]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3839)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.backgroundProcess(StandardContext.java:5612)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1389)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1361)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\GITROOT\adesso\collphir4_backend\target\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar (Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.isMultiRelease(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:121)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResourceSet.getResource(AbstractArchiveResourceSet.java:250)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResourcesInternal(StandardRoot.java:327)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.CachedResource.validateResources(CachedResource.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResources(Cache.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResources(StandardRoot.java:315)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getClassLoaderResources(StandardRoot.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.ExtensionValidator.validateApplication(ExtensionValidator.java:146)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5062)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\GITROOT\adesso\collphir4_backend\target\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar (Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.jarFileNewInstance(JreCompat.java:196)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.jarFileNewInstance(JreCompat.java:181)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResourceSet.openJarFile(AbstractArchiveResourceSet.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.isMultiRelease(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:116)
    ... 17 more
```

Excerpt from my pom.xml:

```xml
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes>
                        %regex[app-(?!${portal.frontend-base}).*],
                        %regex[profiles/(?!${portal.client-code}).*],
                        **/build/**,
                        **/scss/**,
                        **/node_modules/**,
                        **/*.map,
                        **/jsDoc.js
                    </packagingExcludes>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                    <webappDirectory>target/webapp</webappDirectory>
                    <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                    <archive>
                        <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <company>${project.organization.name}</company>
                            <application>${portal.backend-base}</application>
                            <build-date>${buildDateTime}</build-date>
                            <build-revision>${buildRevision}</build-revision>
                            <scm-branch>${scmBranch}</scm-branch>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                    <webResources>
                        <!-- copy/parse context.xml -->
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/resources/META-INF/</directory>
                            <targetPath>META-INF</targetPath>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <includes>
                                <include>context.xml</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                        <!-- copy/parse web.xml -->
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/</directory>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <includes>
                                <include>web.xml</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                        <!-- copy/parse index.html -->
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp/app-${portal.frontend-base}/</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <includes>
                                <include>index*.html</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring-data-jpa.version}</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
                    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9.4</version>
                </dependency>

               <!-- [...] -->
            </dependencies>
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to depend on the file system and an absolute disk path in web apps.  A better idea is to add the resource into your WAR or JAR package and getResourceAsStream from the CLASSPATH.

Comment: Uhm... what? They are inside a war file, Intellij just deploys the exploded artefact. Also I never had problems like this with other web apps and Tomcat...

Comment: IntelliJ is using the exploded WAR, but that's not what will happen when you deploy to an environment.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying, sorry, or what I can change... I can only say I am not depending on the filesystem, the only dependencies are defined in the pom...

Comment: Oh, one thing: some dependencies'-versions are depending on specific maven profiles... Profile A has version 1.0, but if I build with Profile B it could be 1.1 ...

Comment: You lost me.  I only use one profile at a time.  Sounds like a bad idea to me.

Comment: The exception suggests to me that the spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar doesn't appear in the package correctly.  Check your packaging.  I'd also recommend that you try Spring Boot.  Create an executable JAR and stop using WAR and Java EE.

Comment: The weird thing is: All the jars ARE in the specified folder... :-( I mean its basic maven dependency-management, so I dont understand this error...

Comment: Believe IntelliJ.  If it's not finding the JAR, then there's a problem.  How are you creating the package?  Is there a Maven plugin that does it for you?  Or did you set up your artifact creation in IntelliJ?

Comment: It's a maven build, nothing unusual. If I look at the target folder, all the libs are exactly where intellij says they aren't. No maven plugin, just standard maven clean install!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196315/discussion-between-vortilion-and-duffymo).

Comment: I don’t do chat.

Comment: Oo What does THAT mean...?

Comment: FYI: stackoverflow doesnt like long conversations in the comment section... 

I have to use several profiles to control several aspects of the build. Its one application in different "versions" for different customers, so I have to control for which customer to build via profiles. That's the first profile i have to choose, the customer. The second profile is just the "dev-mode", if I select this as well (which I locally always do) then it sets some development-properties. Nothing fancy... I guess the main problem here are the dependency-versions which are set via customer-profile-properties?

Comment: please check mentioned below answer and try to add jar in your pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

Add the jar dependency in your pom.xml -

```
Dependencies : add dependency in your pom.xml

<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
 <version>1.11.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

Build Configuration : 

    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!--<skipMain>true</skipMain> -->
                <skip>true</skip>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>post-unit-test</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                        <dataFile>target/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
                        <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
                        <outputDirectory>target/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <jacoco-agent.destfile>target/jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: They already are in the pom as dependencies! That's why this issue doesn't make sense to me. It must be an Intellij-Problem... It only occurs when deploying the app via Intellij Run-Config. And why should i add all this stuff you added in your pom?